# Objective-C VisualFormatString - Label and TextField side by side with width priority to TextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints

I currently have these tableView cells:

[image]

Each cell is of the same type.  Each has a UILabel on the left and a UITextField on the right.  Some times data may be passed into the text fields upon load and other times users will enter data manually into those fields.

Everything is being done programmatically.  No storyboards.  I'm using Visual Format Strings to style the cells.

This is my problem:
I want the label width to grow with it's given content and the text fields width to fill the remaining space available in the cell.

Here's my code:

```
NSDictionary* views = @{ @"bsyLeftLabel": self.bsyLeftLabel, @"bsyRightGenericTextField": self.bsyRightGenericTextField };

    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-18-[bsyLeftLabel]-[bsyRightGenericTextField]-18-|"]
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:views]];
```

As you can see I have a 18 point padding on the left and right ends of the cell with default spacing between the label and text field.

How do I get the width of the label to be just as big as the text inside of it and the text field to fill the remaining width of the cell?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What result does that code give you? When I do this same setup in the storyboard, I get the result you want. If you're not getting that result, you might need to set the content hugging priority of the label to a higher value than that for the text field (in the storyboard, you get that automatically, I don't know if that happens in code).

If you always want the label to fully display it's text, you also need to raise its content compression resistance to a level higher than the text field (which is 750 by default).

```
[self.label setContentCompressionResistancePriority: 751 forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

Comment: @KraigWastlund, did you try setting the content hugging priority as I suggested?

Comment: setting the content hugging on the label worked, but now the text field's content will go over the label's content.  I need to set the label's width so it always is as big as the text within it.  The problem is, where I'm setting my constraints I do not have access to the text that is within the label.  Is there a way to tell the label to always grow as big as your content is?

Comment: @KraigWastlund If the 2 texts together are too long, what do you want to happen? One of them is going to have to be truncated.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear.  I want the label (on the left) to always size for it's content and the textfield (on the right) to take up remaining space and truncate when needed.

Comment: @KraigWastlund I edited my answer to add how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Content Hugging of the `bsyLeftLabel` to be higher than that of `bsyRightGenericTextField` so the label will be "hugged" around it's content, then the text field will automatically expand to the rest of the space:

```
[self.bsyLeftLabel setContentHuggingPriority:NSLayoutPriorityRequired 
                         forOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationHorizontal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add a constraint of width >= 0 on your UILabel : `@"bsyLeftLabel(>=0)"` to make it adapt to its content ?